# transaction terminated while receiving SIP calls android

Tags: android

I am working on a SIP based application , i have followed SIP-DEMO for reference, everything is working fine , i am able to make app to app calls, receive call but when i am trying to answer the call i get an error "Transaction Terminated" ,error code "-3". Can anybody help me to figure out the cause of problem and come up with a solution, any sort of help is highly appreciated.

Below is the class i have used to Receive Incoming Calls

public class IncomingCallActivity extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.incoming_call_reciever);

    mIntent = Helper.getInstance().getCallIntent();
    mManager = Helper.getInstance().getSipManager();

    initListeners();

    try {

        mCall = mManager.takeAudioCall(mIntent, listener);

    } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    views();

    setClickListenerOnReceiveCall();

    setClickListenerOnEndCall();



}

private void initListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener(){
        @Override
        public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onRinging(call, caller);
            Toast.makeText(context, "onRinging", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCallEstablished(call);
            Toast.makeText(context, "onCallEstablished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mCall.startAudio();
            mCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCallEnded(call);
            Toast.makeText(context, "onCallEnded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onError(call, errorCode, errorMessage);
        }
    };
}

private void views() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mChronometer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    buttonEndCall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEndCall);
    buttonRecieve = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonReceiveCall);
    textViewCallerInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewCallerInfo);
    textViewCallerInfo.setText(mCall.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName());
}

private void setClickListenerOnReceiveCall() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    buttonRecieve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Recieve", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            try {

                mCall.answerCall(30);


            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
}

private void setClickListenerOnEndCall() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    buttonEndCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "Reject", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                mCall.endCall();
                mCall.close();
            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: hi fellow developers, please extend your hands in help, i am still looking for the solution...please help.

Comment: Hi, Have you had any luck, I'm having the same issue myself.

Comment: Myslef too onError -3transaction terminated after accepting the call am getting onError callback